# cannot get value from parse variable in arrow function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I want to parse data.userId from socket transfer_chat, but it looks like I am not getting value userId in sendInitialChatData2. Please help me to find what wrong with my code?

```
 const sendInitialChatData = (userId) => function sendInitialChatData(thread: Thread, userId: userId): Promise<void> {
    const threadData = thread.serialize();
    return Message.findByThreadID(threadData.id).then((history: Array<Message>) => {
      socket.join(threadData.room);
      socket.emit(CHAT_START_EVENT, {
        thread: threadData,
        history: history.map(message => message.serialize()),
      });
      operatorController
        .findOneByUserID(userId)
        .then(operator_transfer =>
          io
            .to(OPERATOR_ROOM)
            .emit(QUEUE_UPDATE_EVENT, { operator: operator_transfer.serialize(), thread: threadData })
        )
    });
 };

 socket.on(
    'transfer_chat',
    heartbeat((data: object) => {
      operatorController
        .findOneByUserID(data.userId)
        .then(data_operator => threadController.pickUpThreadByNIS(data.nis, data_operator))
        .then(sendInitialChatData(data.userId))
        .catch(err => emitError(err, socket));           
    }),
 );
```

Comment: put a `console.log(data)` just above your `operatorController.findOneByUserID` and see if it has a userId key in it

Comment: @Prasanna yes i get the value of data.userId